# Evaluate parametric derivative of a symbolic function in Python

Tags: python, parameters, sympy, derivative

I'm a beginner with Python (v 3.7) and I am trying to evaluate numerically a derivative of a symbolic function that contains parameters but I can't feed the values in a successful way.

I've tried different combinations getting inspiration from reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829395/deriving-a-mathematical-function-in-python) and something also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136697/partial-symbolic-derivative-in-python).

Here is a minimal example that replicates my problem:

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy import*

x, y, a = sym.var('x, y, a')
def f(x,y):
    return a*x**2 + x*y**2
fprime = sym.diff(f(x,y),x)

print(f(1,1))
print(fprime.evalf(subs={x: 1, y: 1}))
```

As expected the output of the first **print** is `a+1` but the issue arrives with the second print because the output I get is `2.0*a*x + y**2` while I wish to obtain `2*a+1`.

How shall I amend my code? I've also tried defining `fprime` separately and run the following:

```py
def fprime(x,y):
    return sym.diff(f(x,y),x)
print(fprime(x,1))
```

but still I can't make any progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use substitution. Use evalf when you are trying to get a number from an expression that is a number. Your, containing unevaluated `a` is not yet a number so evaluation rejects it.

```
>>> fprime.subs({x: 1, y: 1})
2*a + 1
```